# How to make a new column in a dataframe, based on ranges within factors from another, in R

Tags: r

This is a slightly complex issue I am trying to solve in R (R-Studio, R version 3.3.1).

I have two dataframes (DF_A, DF_B) . DF_A is structured like this:

```
Filename   Timestamp
A          11
A          12
A          17 
B          18
B          22
B          23
C          24
C          28
C          30
```

And, DF_B like this:

```
Timestamp
11
12
13
14
15
16
17 
18 
19
...
30
```

And I'd like to be able to move the filename from DF_A to DF_B, based on the range of values seen in each Filename factor from DF_A. So:

```
Timestamp   Filename 
11          A
12          A
13          A
14          A
...
18          B
19          B
...
24          C
```

I was considering getting the min-max timestamp of each factor in DF_A, appending the Filename as they belong to the same range of timestamps in DF_B. Thusfar, I have managed to get the min-max by a solution I found, which turns the dataframe into a datatable- and gets the min/max for each factor:

```
DT_A <- as.data.table(DF_A)
DT[,.SD[which.min(Timestamp)], by = Filename]
DT[,.SD[which.max(Timestamp)], by = Filename]
```

Alas, this is as far as I have gotten. I am not sure how I would apply this to DF_B. The solution can be pretty open here. Curious to see the different solutions. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# import the necessary package
library(data.table)

# create lookup data table
DT_A <- data.table(
  Filename = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
  Timestamp = c(11, 12, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 28, 30)
)

# form data table to be labelled
DT_B <- data.table(
  Timestamp = 11:30
)

# get the minimum and maximum timestamp for each filename
DT_limits <- DT_A[ , 
  .(from = min(Timestamp, na.rm = T),
    to = max(Timestamp, na.rm = T)),
  by = Filename]

## apply a fast overlap
DT_B[ , dummy:= Timestamp]
setkey(DT_limits, from, to)
DT_final <- foverlaps(
  DT_B,
  DT_limits,
  by.x = c("Timestamp", "dummy"),
  nomatch = 0L
)[ , c("from", "to", "dummy") := NULL]

DT_final
# Filename Timestamp
# 1:        A        11
# 2:        A        12
# 3:        A        13
# 4:        A        14
# ...
# 8:        B        18
# 9:        B        19
# ...
# 14:       C        24
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ozan, for your quick response! I would have never known about those functions and been able to do this if it weren't for you. Very helpful

Comment: @Alexander, I'm glad to help! This is just one of many ways to solve it. I'm sure you will be able to find a more efficient solution by yourself once you spend some time on StackOverflow. Cheers!